# DELL PERC H310 mini - firmware upgrade (IT mode) - led behavior

Tags: dell-perc, lsi

I've upgraded the PERC firmware with this guide (https://fohdeesha.com/docs/H310.html) and I have a working server again.

I have these doubts. Anyone has faced this?

1. **Slot ID**. Server is 1U (R420) therefore only a single line of trays (4 bays). But the firmware has that ID as 4, 5, 6, 7 -- seems like the 2U chassis (8 bays). See attached picture: [POST list of devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqpYj.jpg)
2. **LED**. Those lights have a reason (see below), but only the lower LED is working (flashes whenever the drive is accessed). Maybe this is related to misplaced slot ID?

> 1 - Hard Drive Carrier Status LEDs
>
> The LEDs on the physical disk carrier indicates the state of each physical disk. Each drive carrier in your enclosure has two LEDs: an activity LED (green) and a status LED (bicolor, green/amber) as shown below. The activity LED flashes whenever the drive is accessed.
>
> Off. Slot is empty, drive is not yet discovered by the system.
>
> Steady green. Drive is online.
>
> Green flashing (250 milliseconds [ms]). Drive is being identified or is being prepared for removal.
>
> Green flashing (On 400 ms, Off 100 ms). Drive is rebuilding or undergoing a Replace Member operation.
>
> Amber flashing (125 ms). Drive has failed.
>
> Green/amber flashing (Green On 500 ms / Amber On 500 ms, Off 1000 ms). Predicted failure reported by drive.
>
> Green flashing (Green On 3000 ms, Off 3000 ms, Amber On 3000 ms, Off 3000 ms). Drive being spun down by user request or other non-failure condition.